# Telegram bot нow add bot to group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Telegram bot on python using the pyTelegramBotAPI library.
Want to add a bot to a group when calling the command /start@BotName how does it work with bot @TrueMafiaBot
How i can do this?

Comment: Have your read the readme?
What have you tried?
What doesn't work?
Where do you stumble in the tutorial?

Comment: I don't have tutorials for this. I read the readme and could not find an answer. I tried to google but did not find anything suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following link and send it to the user:

`t.me/BotUsername?startgroup=botstart`

Replace `BotUsername` with your bots username and when the User clicks the link their client will prompt to select a group the bot should be added to.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need

Comment: It changed now, @ should removed
`t.me/BotUsername?startgroup=botstart`

Answer (score 1):

My final code for add bot to group by button

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()  # Keyboard
    key_add_to_group = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Add to group', url='http://t.me/evil_cards_bot?startgroup=test')
    keyboard.add(key_add_to_group)  # Add button to keyboard
    response_text = 'Add bot to group.'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=response_text, reply_markup=keyboard)
```